# Bootstrap: put two tables in one boostrap column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 tables: 2 shorter ones that should occupy 3 bootstrap columns on the left and 1 longer and bigger table that should take 9 columns on the right. Below is the code, both smaller tables appear on one row while the bigger one is below.

```css
body {
  padding: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left-side-top" class="col-3">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Left top</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="left-side-bottom" class="col-3">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Left bottom</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="right-side" class="col-9">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Longer table header</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

It should appear like this:

[image]

How do I edit my layout? I'm using `Bootstrap 4.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing the second small table in a different `col-3` div element, just place it under the first small table in the first `col-3` div element, check the code below

```css
body {
  padding: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left-side-top" class="col-3">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Left top</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
         
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Left bottom</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
      
      <div id="right-side" class="col-9">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Longer table header</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left-side-top" class="col-3">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>Left top</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="left-side-bottom">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>Left bottom</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>



      <div id="right-side" class="col-9">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>Longer table header</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body></html>
```

I've altered your div's position. I hope it helps....

Answer (score 1):

Your layout should be like

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <!--Place your 2 small tables here-->
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-9">
  <!--Place your 1 big table here-->
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
     
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Left top</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
     
      </div>
      
    
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Left bottom</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
     
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <div id="right-side" class="col-9">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-fit">
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Longer table header</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]